# PageVisibility API - Change in browser console tab to act like active

Tags: javascript

I am parsing some data from some website. The problem is that the data stops refreshing if browser tab for this page is not opened. I guess they use [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilityState).

Is there any way how to manually change page visibility status through console? So basically I want the page to act like my browser tab is active and not minimized.

Comment: What do you mean by visibility? `blur` and `focus`events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visibility api probably listens for events. When events trigger the page become visible/invisibile. You can create a synthetic event and thus trick the api. Depending on which events api uses you can try something like this:

```
e = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
e.initEvent("focus", false, true);
window.dispatchEvent(e)
```

If `focus` doesn't work, try to simulate events from [wiki](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API).